# How do I make a JavaScript bookmarklet to add to part of the URL?u

Tags: javascript, url, pdf, edit

I am trying to make a JavaScript bookmarklet to go to the next page in my math book. The URL is something like `website.com/book_year_pagenumber.pdf` so page 500 would be `website.com/book_year_0500.pdf`.

I need something to add 1 to the 500 to make it `website.com/book_year_0501.pdf`, but it has to work on any page like from page 200 to 201 or page 573 to 574. Does anyone know how to do that?

EDIT: maybe this will help. I want it to turn "http://my.hrw.com/math06_07/student/pdf/english/alg2/alg2_07_0500.pdf" 
into 
"http://my.hrw.com/math06_07/student/pdf/english/alg2/alg2_07_0501.pdf"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't `javascript:(function(){var url=location.href.split('book_year_');var currentPage=+(url[1].split('.')[0])+1;while(currentPage.toString().length<4){ currentPage='0'+currentPage;}location.href=url[0]+('book_year_')+currentPage+'.pdf';})()` work ?

A little walk through :

```
// declare that this bookmarklet is a js script
javascript:(function(){
  // parse the current url
  var url = location.href.split('book_year_');
  // get the page number, transform it to a Number and increment it
  var currentPage = +(url[1].split('.')[0])+1;
  // add the leading zeroes
  while(currentPage.toString().length<4){ currentPage = '0' + currentPage;}
  // set the new url      
  location.href= url[0]+('book_year_')+currentPage+'.pdf';
// call the function
})()
```

Comment: Kind of, but it adds "C80582C28293361Aj7DquSwV8KLfk1oSUc2ogCmAH1OC5OCtThlX09QYYHofDoD4uvIKQ5ZtN1JmTc4B" Or some othe random letters and numbers to the end of the url

Comment: wow what? That is really strange, I only tested on a link though but it seemed to work, I'll try as a bookmarklet but I'm wondering what could produce it :) Are you sure you did copied the code correctly? Just tested and it does work, except for one little caveat : it removes the first 0, will fix it

Comment: Never mind that's just the website freaking out, but it says it doesn't exist even though I can get there by typing the url

Comment: Fixed the leading zeroes issue. Just tested on your live link and it does work (you need to change both `book_year_` to `alg2_07_` though.

Comment: I also shortened it a bit: javascript:u=location.href.split('alg2_07_');c=+(u[1].split('.')[0])+1;while(c.toString().length<4){c='0'+c;}location.href=u[0]+('alg2_07_')+c+'.pdf';

Comment: you could golf  even more by setting 'alg2_07_' to a one char variable and the toString part could be replaced by `while((c+'').length<4)`